# Weird #define declaration, can't understand to what it expands

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have this `#define` statement in legacy code I'm inspecting in **C**.

```
#define STEP(x)         case x: STEP ## x : WPAN_Startup_Step = x;
```

This is a macro to replace cases in a very big switch state machine.
I can't understand what's going on in this macro. What does it expand to ?

Comment: In addition to STEP(x), is there a `#define STEP` anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`##` does a concatenation, this means that the result will be something like this:

```
STEP(1)

case 1: STEP1: WPAN_Startup_Step = 1;
```

or another example:

```
STEP(v)

case v: STEPv: WPAN_Startup_Step = v;
```

this macro does not make to much sense to me, since it generates `x: STEPx:`
maybe a usage example would clarify this.

if you want to see the expansion of a macro use: `gcc -E program.c`

also a good place to learn about macros: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

Comment: Ok, got it, the programmer used "STEP ## x" to define a label to goto... I hate this kind of code programming...

Comment: Oh, ew. Loop unrolling by gotos to macro-generated labels. Ick.

Comment: @Mellowcandle That you hate it just means that you are, or have potential to be, a good programmer, unlike whoever wrote that abomination macro.